# how to add calendar pop up next to date column

Tags: php, javascript

How do I put calendar next to date input field? in php
thanks.

```
 <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label">Date:</label>
     <div class="controls">
        <input required name="receiving_date" type="date" id="receiving_date"
               class="input-xlarge" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its the same...I want a calendar icon appear next to date input..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have an image that is going to be clickable and will open the wanted datepicker plugin. For example:

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label">Date:</label>
 <div class="controls">
    <input required name="receiving_date" type="date" id="receiving_date"
           class="input-xlarge" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" />
<a href="javascript:showCalendar('date')"><img src="date.gif" width="19" height="17" border="0"></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

and in the javascript you call the showCalendar function. Detailed example on this page:

```
http://www.yxscripts.com/cal_core_lite/cal_list_lite.html
```

Hope this helps.